# Why does updating the priority of existing key yield inconsistent results?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am constructing a min-priority queue with the following requirements:

- The elements have a separate priority map.
- An index may be inserted again with an updated priority, the position of the "old" index is not important after the insertion.

Below follows a minimal example which demonstrates an unexpected result. In the code I insert into the priority queue `1`, `2`, and `3` with priorities`10`, `20`, and `30` respectively. I then change the priority `20 -> 5` for index `2`, and insert it again.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  std::map<int, int> weight;
  weight[1] = 10;
  weight[2] = 20;
  weight[3] = 30;

  auto compare = [&](int left, int right) { return weight[left] > weight[right]; };
  std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(compare)> queue(compare);

  queue.push(1);
  queue.push(2);
  queue.push(3);
  weight[2] = 5;
  queue.push(2);

  while (!queue.empty()) {
    printf("%i ", queue.top());
    queue.pop();
  }
}
```

Running the code above gives output `1 2 2 3`. I would expect this to output `2 2 1 3` or possibly `2 1 2 3`. Strangely, changing  `weight[2] = 5;` to `weight[2] = 35;` gives output `1 3 2 2` which is expected. According to cppreference this is implemented as a binary heap but I cannot understand why I would get the first results.

Comment: Because the data structure doesn't support it. It already has the data in its own order, and it doesn't know you changed it. You need to delete and re-insert the item.

Comment: 'The priority queue should not be aware of any specific priority values ... it only knows if one is greater than the other': of course: and if you change that relation without telling it, you have broken it. As you have here.

Answer (score 2):

The program exhibits undefined behavior as a result of broken preconditions.

By changing the weights which are stored externally to the heap you are essentially changing the ordering relation between heap elements.

Consequently, after the ordering relation has changed, the elements already stored in the underlying container no longer constitute a **valid heap**.

That breaks the preconditions for pretty much every heap operation from that point on.

Note that [`std::priority_queue`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/priority.queue) is a simple wrapper defined in terms of calls to the standard algorithms `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, etc.

For example if we take `priority_queue::push`, it calls `push_heap` ([[containers.priqueue.members]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/containers#priqueue.members-1)):

> `void push(const value_type& x);`
>
> *Effects:* As if by:
>
> ```
> c.push_back(x);
> push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
> ```

And `push_heap` (see [[algorithms.push.heap]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/algorithms#push.heap)) has a precondition:

> *Requires:* The range `[first, last - 1)` shall be a **valid heap**.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional thinking I believe I understand why this is happening. When adding the lower priority, it passes the check that all children are greater or equal to its parent since only the leaf to which it was added onto is checked. After which no swaps are executed and results in an "invalid" heap.

I made an image to illustrate this. Here it is also easy to see that if you initially added the elements in another order, say `1`, `3`, `2`, so that the leftmost node has priority `30`, it would give output `2 2 1 3`.

[image: min-priority queue]